# In JavaScript how do I get all matches using regex instead of the last one

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling to figure out how to get this regex to work without needing a loop. Here's the code that works:

```
var template = {name: "Oscar", anotherName: "your twin", hello: 'world'}
var str = "Hello, {{name}} I'm {{anotherName}}. Hello to the {{hello}}"

Object.keys(template).forEach(function (keyName) {
    pattern = new RegExp('{{' + keyName + '}}', 'g');
    str = str.replace(pattern, template[keyName]);
})

// => str "Hello, Oscar I'm your twin. Hello to the world"
```

The thing about this code I don't like is that it's in a loop generating regex when I feel like a regex should be able to handle this use case. However, my regex is always only matching the last item. I was doing regex like `str.match(/({{.}})/gi)` but then only the `{{hello}}` was getting matched.

Preferably I'd like to do something where I can get all matches in an array and then map the array like `matchesFromRegex.map(match => template[match]).join('')`

Also, I'm in an vanilla JS environment so `.matchAll` (which isn't supported in IE) wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a RegExp string, `{` has a special meaning (it lets you set a cardinality for a match, like `\d{5}` for five digits).

Use `new RegExp('\\{\\{' + keyName + '}}', 'g');` instead. The double backslash in JavaScript will create a backslash, which will escape the `{` character.

If you want to avoid the loop, you can use the function-based version of `replace` instead:

```
const pattern = /\{\{([^}]*)}}/g;
str.replace(pattern, (_, key) => template[key]);
```

To break it down, `pattern` has a capture group (the parts in `()`). The `String.prototype.replace` function can let you supply a function for doing replacements, which will be passed your match results.

Comment: Wonderful! thank you! Worked perfectly and doesn't mutate the original string 

Comment: If others find this, one slight modification I made is the code above will return `undefined` _in_ the string if the template key is missing. I did `|| _` so that if it doesnt exist it falls back to the template tag being rendered as opposed to undefined.